# Targetting .NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I've found other references that say all I should need to do is change the TargetFrameworkVersion in the .vcxproj file from 4.0 to 3.5.

However, this doesn't work.

My code still compiles. But when I try to reference it from 3.5 code, it says that it is from the wrong framework version. I can confirm with Reflector that it is still targeting the 4.0 runtime.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: You have to do it by hand so that's always one way to get it wrong.  You must also have VS2008 installed on the same machine.  Document your question better.

Comment: Ugh. I found the problem. Your comment about doing it by hand made me go back and look. I had used 3.5 instead of v3.5. It accepted it and compiled, oddly. Just always as 4.0. I should either delete this question or give you the answer.